# font size doesnt work in tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I just added font size option in tinymce. Inside html editor it displays correctly changed font size but it doesn't save that changed content. I dont think that xss filtering is issue here since other formatting works (bold, italic, ...).

I initialize tinymce like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea", theme: "modern", width: 930, height: 300,                
                plugins: [                    
                    "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                    "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager"
                ],
                toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | sizeselect | fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
                toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
                image_advtab: true,
                external_filemanager_path: "/Scripts/filemanager/",
                filemanager_title: "Responsive Filemanager",
                external_plugins: {"filemanager": "/Scripts/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: can you show us, what code you get inside the editor using the codeplugin and what you get afterwards when you wnat to use the content elsewhere